# Git not pulling changes in AWS ec2 user data

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, amazon-ec2, aws-auto-scaling

Hi sorry if this is super obvious but I can't seem to figure it out.  I have an auto scaling group setup in AWS for deploying an api server.  Instances are launched using a template with an AMI I made from a previously running EC2 instance that has git setup with  my credentials to communicate over ssh. On each instance spin up I want the system to pull changes from git and build according to a docker compose yaml file.  My user data in the AWS launch template is

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ubuntu/git-repo-directory
git pull origin main
sudo docker compose up --build -d
```

What's strange is that the `docker` command seems to be running but the code is not pulled and updated from remote git repository.  Am I doing something wrong?